# finding biggest number in a Postscript stack

Tags: loops, compare, max, postscript

I can't get the code to work to right. 
I am comparing the top two number on the stack. the highest number will end up on top and lower numbers will be rolled back to the bottom.

```
    count 
    /length exch def        
    length {
             1 index 0 index gt { 
                   2 1 roll
                   count 1 sub -1 roll
            }if
    }repeat
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, be very careful about choosing names for your definitions. `length` is the name of an operator. So while your definition is in effect (presumably in `userdict`) the operator (in `systemdict`) is not accessible by name*.

For any tricky stack-manipulation code, it's a very good habit to write comments describing the stack at the end of each line. This is where you can use "free" variable names.

```
count    % ... n
```

Now, since we're using this value immediately, it doesn't actually need to be defined at all. Just leave it on the stack.

```
{ %

} repeat
```

Now loops may seem tricky to document the stack but really it's exactly the same. The repeat loop takes the repeat-count argument off of the stack, so the procedure begins with the contents just below.

```
{ % ...
```

`1 index 0 index` would be better as `1 index 1 index` (right? because the first one shifted the stack depth). But it's best as `2 copy`.

```
    2 copy gt { % ... x y  (x>y)
```

The `(x>y)` here is not on the stack but represents *knowledge* of the variables' relationship.
`2 1 roll` is better as `exch`.

```
        exch   % ... y x  (x>y)
        count 1 sub -1 roll  %
```

This will pull the second-from-the-bottom to the top. See my guide to the `roll` operator: [Positive j to roll away, negative to retrieve.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997536/how-do-you-keep-the-roll-operator-straight)

```
        exch   % a b ... y x  (x>y)
```

But if `x<y` then we still want to roll the next number from the bottom, right? So the `if` clause should end here.

```
    } if
    count 1 sub -1 roll  % a ... y x b
```

If you remove the `1 sub`, then it grabs the bottom of stack. And then I think it should do what you describe.

```
} repeat
```

Assembled.

```
count    % ... n
{ % ... 
    2 copy gt { % a ... x y  (x>y)
        exch    % a ... y x  (x>y)
    } if        % a ... y x  (x>y)
    count -1 roll  % ... y x a  (x>y)
} repeat
```

---

*Edit, one day later:* Um. Problem. It's not right. Since the `roll` happens *after* the comparison, there's going to be one extra unnecessary `roll` before the loop terminates which places one of the smaller, rejected values on the top.

A quick fix is to add

```
count 1 roll   % a ... y x  (x>y)
```

at the very end, after the loop. But I think a nicer way is to roll first, *then* compare.

It's a "fence-posting" problem if ever I saw one.

```
a b c d e f g h
            g>h
          f>g
        e>f
      d>e
    c>d
  b>c
a>b
```

So we only actually need n-1 comparisons. Which leads to this version, which I think should work better.

```
count 1 sub  % a b c ... x y n-1
{
    count -1 roll  % b c ... x y a
    2 copy gt { exch } if  % b c ... x y a  (a>y)
} repeat
```

There's still one unnecessary `roll` (the very first one), but it's harmless now.

[*] It's still accessible in procedures which have had `bind` applied.